# Laravel 5.3 - Custom API Guard

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 endpoint :

```
Route::get('user', function () {
    $data = ...;

    return response()->json($data);
});

Route::get('user-premium', function () {
    $data = ...;

    return response()->json($data);
});
```

in user-premium, Ii need to restrict aaccess with token (but I don't want to use jwt or database)

I plan to use env variable, like `API_TOKEN=xxx`

So, how to make custom guard base on env variable

my goal is request `/api/user-premium/?token=xxx`, `xxx` is value from env variable

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [this](https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51)

In short:

1. Add an api_token column to your `user` table
2. Wrap your routes with the `Auth::api` middleware
3. Get the logged user like this `Auth::guard('api')->user()`
4. Update your `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate` to handle `$request->wantsJson()`